# Error trying to download the information from repository

Tags: apt

I'm getting all the time an error when try to update some Drivers, Controllers (It talks about the way to download some data from repositories) on Linux Mint 18 KDE Edition, how could I fix it?

[image: LINUX MINT 18 ERROR]

```
W:The repository 'cdrom://Linux Mint 18 _Sarah_ - Release amd64 20160904 xenial Release' does not have a Release file.
W:Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
W:See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E:Failed to fetch cdrom://Linux Mint 18 _Sarah_ - Release amd64 20160904/dists/xenial/contrib/binary-amd64/Packages
Please use apt-cdrom to make this CD-ROM recognized by APT. apt-get update cannot be used to add new CD-ROMs
E:Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

UPDATE:

I'm tired also getting a message saying that "check your internet connection" and as you can see, I'm wired....

[image: ERROR REPOSITORIES CONNECTIVITY]

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't know about Linux & Unit topic, close it please

Comment: Hi! There is no need to close your question. In fact, here, on Linux and Unix website, your question is at home! AskUbuntu is only about the official Ubuntu distros, while Linux and Unix is about all the other Linux distributions, including yours, Linux Mint. :-)

Comment: Oh thanks you very much, so I used to boot just in ubuntu, and that was my mistake jeje

Comment: "Please use apt-cdrom to make this CD-ROM recognized by APT"

Comment: RESOLVED! Thanks, unchecking CD-ROM from PPA tab